# Get the CSV file data in Docker compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker, csv, go, docker-compose

I have a CLI application that gets the CSV file from the PostgreSQL database. Although running the code creates the CSV file and puts the data into CSV but running the application through docker compose does not do it.

I put the volumes in the `app` service but it didn't work.

**Docker compose file**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "while true; do echo 'App is running'; sleep 10; done"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: flow
      POSTGRES_SSL: disable
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - /path/to/store/CSV/file:/app/data

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: flow
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.22.0-alpine3.19

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod /app
COPY go.sum /app

COPY . /app

RUN go mod download

RUN go build -o flow .

CMD ["./flow"]
```

**Data getting function**

```
func GetBudgetData(filepath, filename string) error {
    bv := new(BudgetVariables)
    db, err := budget_db.Connection()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    query := "SELECT categories, amounts FROM Budget"
    rows, err := db.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    file, err := os.Create(filepath + "/" + filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
    defer writer.Flush()

    header := []string{"Category", "Amount"}
    if err := writer.Write(header); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(&bv.Category, &bv.Amount); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        data := []string{bv.Category, bv.Amount}
        if err := writer.Write(data); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Successfully created a '%s' file in '%s'\n", filename, filepath)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: If you have a process whose primary goal is to write local files, it will be easier to run it outside Docker.  If it does its task and exits immediately, it's not a good match for Compose's long-running service model.  Can you build and run the application outside a container, even if the underlying data comes from a container database?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have a CLI budget application in which you create, edit, remove and get the budget information. I have dealt with all of them except the get functionality that how to get the CSV file data using docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your Dockerfile's [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#cmd) ("`./flow`") which executes your script by using [`command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#command) in the compose file.

[From the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#command):

> `command` overrides the default command declared by the container
> image, for example by Dockerfile's `CMD`

Comment: Should I remove the `CMD` from the Dockerfile?

Comment: You need the `CMD` to execute your script. You can get rid of the `command` in the compose file.

Comment: I wrote the `command` in the compose file because the `app` container was exiting right after creation. I wanted to run the container in order to execute it.

Comment: If your `main()` function is designed to execute a task and then exit, in order to keep the container alive (without exiting immediately after creation), keep the `commands` in the docker-compose. Once the container is up, you can run `docker exec <container-id> flow` command. This allows you to run the `flow` binary inside the container.

Comment: By keeping the commands in the docker-compose file, I am running the command, `docker exec <container-id> ./flow budget .get ...`  but it is not creating the csv file.